# iPhone using webkit-transform translate 3d

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, jquery-mobile

I was using:

```
Data.$notification
     .delay(1500)
     .animate({
        right: '+=' + (Data.$notification.width() + 45)
      }, 700)
     .delay(2500)
      .animate({
           right: '-=' + (Data.$notification.width() + 45)
      }, 700, function() { 
          $(this).remove(); 
      });
```

But it's not smooth enough, so taking peoples advice I want to use translate 3D css.
ATM I can't get it working, I've tried:

```
Data.$notification
.delay(1500)
.addClass('move-into-view')
.delay(2500)
.removeClass('move-into-view').addClass('move-outof-view')
.delay(1500)
.remove();
```

Where

```
.rotate-notification.move-into-view {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-175px, 0, 0);
}
.rotate-notification.move-outof-view {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(175px, 0, 0);
}
```

Is this actually possible? or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your CSS where you actually define the `-webkit-transition`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.delay()` only works with a queue:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

So a suggested route would be:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    Data.$notification.addClass('move-into-view');
    setTimeout(function () {
        Data.$notification.removeClass('move-into-view').addClass('move-outof-view');
        setTimeout(function () {
            Data.$notification.remove();
        }, 1500);
    }, 2500);
}, 1500);
```

Also you need to set a `transition` rule in your CSS for an animation:

```
.rotate-notification {
-webkit-transition : -webkit-transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition : -moz-transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition : -ms-transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition : -o-transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
        transition : transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
.rotate-notification.move-into-view {
-webkit-transform : translate3d(175px, 0, 0);
   -moz-transform : translate(175px, 0);
    -ms-transform : translate(175px, 0);
     -o-transform : translate(175px, 0);
        transform : translate(175px, 0);
}
.rotate-notification.move-outof-view {
-webkit-transform : translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -moz-transform : translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform : translate(0, 0);
     -o-transform : translate(0, 0);
        transform : translate(0, 0);
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vJHvA/4/

Note that if you don't use something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) to check browser compatibility and adapt accordingly then you can break functionality in browsers other than Mobile Safari (for example the Android Browser which is also a WebKit browser).

Comment: Thanks again for your answer Japser, really great :) What a pain haha, I'm have to do it though, the animation on iPad in-app-mode is terrible!